# Waiting to acquire read lock on a previously updated row within the same transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-deadlocks, locks

within a transaction with read committed isolation level if you do an update on a set of rows and then do a select on the same set of rows will sql server not reuse the x locks it acquires on the index when doing the update to do the next select or will it try to get a new set of locks on the index.
I'm having a deadlock scenario where the two processes are fighting for a index key lock-one of the two resources that is locked. This happens when one of the processes has already done an update and then does a select on the same rows. My question is how come that process waits to acquire a key lock on the index when it has already gotten the x lock on the same row in the previous step.

Comment: Is the SELECT being attempted by the same connection that performed the update? Your question mentions two processes, which could mean that a different connection is involved, so I just want to make sure.

Comment: yes, the select is within the same transaction that did the update